# File not found exception while downloading android expansion file

Tags: android, cordova-plugins, apk-expansion-files

I'm creating a cordova plugin to download expansion files. 
Currently, I'm implementing that the expansion files will be downloaded manually.

The request will be send, but I get the error

```
aborting request for download main.1000004.my.name.app.obb: while writing destination file: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/obb/my.name.app/main.1000004.my.name.app.obb.tmp: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-20 17:12:12.930 15355-15631/my.name.app W/System.err: com.google.android.vending.expansion.downloader.impl.DownloadThread$StopRequest: while writing destination file: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/obb/my.name.app/main.1000004.my.name.app.obb.tmp: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.vending.expansion.downloader.impl.DownloadThread.writeDataToDestination(DownloadThread.java:515)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.vending.expansion.downloader.impl.DownloadThread.transferData(DownloadThread.java:350)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.vending.expansion.downloader.impl.DownloadThread.executeDownload(DownloadThread.java:308)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.vending.expansion.downloader.impl.DownloadThread.run(DownloadThread.java:236)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.vending.expansion.downloader.impl.DownloaderService.onHandleIntent(DownloaderService.java:1086)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.vending.expansion.downloader.impl.CustomIntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(CustomIntentService.java:104)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
W/System.err: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/obb/my.name.app/main.1000004.my.name.app.obb.tmp: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:127)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.vending.expansion.downloader.impl.DownloadThread.writeDataToDestination(DownloadThread.java:496)
W/System.err:   ... 8 more
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
0W/System.err:    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
```

Actually, my current main expansion version is 1000013. But it searches for 1000004. The content is the same, so it's not the problem.

The rights should be available

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Any idea why this could happen?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this is happening because the Google Play Console does not have a correct expansion file associated with your current version code. Make sure that you uploaded and selected a correct expansion file along with your APK in Play Console.

If it doesn't help, check if your external storage can be mounted by calling `Helpers.isExternalMediaMounted()`. Your device may not have an SD card (emulator?). Additionally, you may want to check if your app has access to the OBB directory by calling `Helpers.canWriteOBBFile(Context)`.

I recommend using the updated Downloader Library included in [Better APK Expansion](https://github.com/bolein/better-apk-expansion) package. It has several issues fixed and also provides simplified API that minimizes chances to shoot yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 0):

If you reach here and didn't find an answer then please try add this to Mainfests   `<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >`